# Nginx: how to view what files are in downloading state?

Tags: linux, web-services, web-applications, nginx

I still wait for the answer.

I need to view if someone is downloading a specific file at this moment. The initial problem: I would like to know when someone interrupts downloading the file.

The server configuration:

```
server 
{

    listen 80;
    server_name mysite.com;

    location /ugp/
    {
        alias /www/ugp/;
    }
    break;
}
```

A user can download files from http://mysite.com/ugp/, for example http://mysite.com/ugp/1.mp3.

**UPDATE**.

It's no so obviously how to do it analyzing access.log. Some browsers send 206 code when user stops downloading (Google Chrome) some not (HTC player, mobile application):

```
85.145.8.243 - - [18/Jan/2013:16:08:41 +0300] "GET /ugp/6.mp3 HTTP/1.1" 200 10292776 "-" "HTC Streaming Player htc_wwe / 1.0 / htc_ace / 2.3.5"
85.145.8.243 - - [18/Jan/2013:16:08:41 +0300] "GET /ugp/2.mp3 HTTP/1.1" 200 697216 "-" "HTC Streaming Player htc_wwe / 1.0 / htc_ace / 2.3.5"
85.145.8.243 - - [18/Jan/2013:16:09:44 +0300] "GET /ugp/7.mp3 HTTP/1.1" 200 4587605 "-" "HTC Streaming Player htc_wwe / 1.0 / htc_ace / 2.3.5"
```

Comment: A `/var/log/nginx/mysite-access.log` analysis (last line `tail -1 file`) is not what you want?

Comment: @ring0 It's not obvously how to do it analyzing access log. See my update please.

Answer (score 1):

In order to offer more flexibility, you can add a PHP server, and publish URLs like

```
  http://mysite.com/download.php?file=2.mp3
```

the `download.php` reads the file from its location (eg `/var/www/files/2.mp3`), having a suggested code. ( [Headers](http://php.net/manual/en/function.header.php) )

```
<?php

  // Here you know precisely that a download is requested

  $path = '/home/var/www/files';
  $file = "$path/" . $_GET['file']; // check user input!
  $size = filesize($file);
  $read = 0;

  $state = 'downloading ' . $file;

  // echo headers for a binary file download 

  @ $f = fopen ($file, 'r');
  if ( $f ) {
    // Output 100 bytes in each iteration
    while (($chunk = fread($f, 100)) !== false) {
      // specify somewhere $state, still downloading
      echo $chunk;
      $read += strlen($chunk);
    }
    fclose ($f);
  }
  if ($read >= $size) 
    $state = 'done';
  else
    $state = 'fail';
?>
```

This is an exemple to provide an algorithm - *not* tested at all! But should be pretty close from a download code (usually *readfile* is used, but it reads the file one shot)

Comment: There is a lot of literature about how to install a nginx+php-fpm on Linux like [this](http://www.howtoforge.com/installing-nginx-with-php5-and-php-fpm-and-mysql-support-lemp-on-ubuntu-12.04-lts) as PHP files needs a special recognition pattern and processing in *nginx*.

Comment: Thanks. It's not so important what programming language we use, isn't it? I understand your PHP code.

Comment: PHP is easier to implement and program. Of course, it would work also in Java, Perl or even C...

Comment: I do not understand (in your code) why we expect that fread returns false when a user interrupts downloading? The audio file is on a server and the function returns false only if it reaches the end of the file.

Comment: Edited to specify how to detect a failure. From the *fread* page there is a case that returns *false* when a time out occurs on the connection. The loop allows to know that the download started, and then is still in progress, the size check to detect an anomaly. Unfortunately, for small files the time out may not be detected (the PHP script will have bufferized the whole output before the connection problem / cut is detected). Unless you do a *java applet* or a *flash* script (both are more complex to implement) this is probably the most you can get.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at the nginx [extended status module](http://wiki.nginx.org/Extended_status_module).

Comment: Excuse me, I don't know how to use the module. I can't find the docs. Could you give me the reference?